# I'm trying to write a story connected with the theory of Hollow Earth

Tags: science-fiction, worldbuilding-process, hollow-earth

I cannot post here the links yet, but you can just search it up, there's so many links out there that will explain to you the theory.

Honestly, I don't believe in this theory but I found it interesting. You get my point?

I actually tried to write a short story about this because I found it interesting. But I don't know what ways can I improve my story about this fiction.

**Things to remember: I am writing this story not as a true to world story, but a plain fiction. So that would mean I would include powers, uncommon strength, etc. I would not take the whole theory itself, but just some of it. (I mean, just the hollow earth but i would not include the partly angels in the original theory)**

So, I posted this not to ask about your opinions if this is pretty cool or what, but I just want to know what points should I consider in making a fictional story. Much more better if you will include some of your stories, already made or not, (if you have one), so I will know tips from more advanced writers since I am just a beginner and this is my first fictional story. Thanks guys!

Comment: Hello Book. I think you may want to ask that question on [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/). If you have questions specifically about Hollow Earth, we may be of some help to you.

Comment: The question you need to ask here involves the conditions or whatever necessary to make a hollow earth reasonably plausible despite its evident impossibility. You have jumped in the deep end, but sometimes that's the best way to learn.

Comment: @BookStriker I've noticed the moderators to do the transfer.

Comment: @a4android sorry for that. so what topics can I post in this site?

Comment: @BookStriker http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Basically questions about worldbuilding. Don't be sorry. It's a steep learning curve. You will find questions need to be focused and specific. About a hollow earth, concentrate on asking what is needed to make it work. The easy answer is nothing. But what you want is something to make the impossible seem possible. This is fiction, it doesn't need to be realistic. Explain that in your question & people will try to help.

Comment: @arandroid hmm I don't really get the point. Favor, can you edit this for me? Just once. So I can understand how questions with this site work.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Book Striker. I would suggest browsing the questions tagged [tag:hollow-earth]. That will both give you some insight into your topic of interest and provide examples of the types of questions the Worldbuilding SE supports. We are more than happy to help with the development of your world, but questions about your story (plot, characters, etc.) are off-topic here.

Comment: In addition to what @Frostfyre wrote above, note that questions about *writing*, including how to tell your story, are off topic here. Some such questions may be on topic on [writers.se], see https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. We are here to help you construct your world; the story you decide to tell within it is out of scope for Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to migrate this question to writers as it stands since it would almost certainly be closed as too broad there. Your best bet would be to look on writers (use the search) for similar questions and read the answers then if you still have any questions about the world (ask here) or the writing (ask there) post a new question :)

Comment: The problem with writers though is that they aren't looking to answer questions that ask "how can I write...." or basically do the writing for them but rather assist in key plot points.  Without much of a story created it seems, this would probably be turned down in that sense.  Still worth a try though as there are many great writers there who can help with many aspects of story.  In terms of world building, I would offer to help edit but I know little about hollow-earth and still not sure exactly what you are looking for help with.